Is there any definitive Conclusion as to what "The Great Tree" is in Genesis 12:6 and 13:18?
The NIV translation of the O.T. mentioned the place where Abraham sojourned as "the site of the Great Tree" of Moreh.

Abraham passed thru the land to the site of the great tree of Moreh at Shechem. (Genesis 12:6)


He went to live near the Great trees of Mamre (Hebron). (Genesis 13:18)

The NIV Exhaustive Concordance translated elon (Hebrew, #471) as great tree ten times. (See also Genesis 18:1, 35:4, Judges 9:6) Whereas others translate this word as "oak tree" or the "terebinth tree"---or even just as "the plains of Moreh"! Some as "the grove of oaks". (See Judges 9:6, KJV, "the plain of Shechem") Others prefer to call this tree "the terpentine tree."
Josephus noted that "the tree of Abraham" near Hebron was revered as a respected (holy?) site. (Wars 4.533, Ant. 1.186)
The JPS Torah Commentary (Nahum M. Sarna, 1989) alleged that it was "some mighty tree with sacred association." (p. 91) John Calvin considered it an "oak tree" and that Gen. 13:18 referred to a "grove of oaks." Leupold on the O.T.-Genesis  considered it to mean "a big tree" (generic Hebrew translation) and thought it to be the turpentine or terebinth tree, an not oak. And he warned against the supposition that it involved animistic religious observances. (Compare Deuteronomy 16:21, and its prohibition against groves.)
Matthew Henry in his commentary just translated these two verses as "unto the place of Shechem, unto the plain of Moreh." (Comm. vol. 1) But on the other hand, the Zondervan Pictorial Encyclopedia authors noted that this word "denotes a strong, hardy tree. It is presumed that the Israelites sacrificed to idols under terebinth trees because 'the shadow thereof is good' since it provided concealment."  They added

This long-lived tree is, common enough in Pal. growing to a height of thirty-five ft. In the dark valley of Elah, David slew Goliath---perhaps that is the reason Goliath did not easily see the slung stone.  (P. 678)

There is an underlying motive evident by some translators who are hesitant to speak of a "famous" tree in order to to avoid associating Abraham with any type of pagan animistic worship. Hence the use of "plain of Moreh" or "great tree."
Is there worry justified? Is this just an ordinary "big tree"? Or are the commentators valid in associating some kind of pagan worship with the Patriarchs per this tree. What is the latest manuscript and archaeological evidence? What is the consensus of opinion in modern Judeo-Christian academia that will help in the exegesis of these verses?

This is simply much unfounded speculation.  All that we know is that Abraham lived near some very well-known trees in the area.  They are almost certainly long gone now.

There is no "definitive conclusion" or consensus but we can safely presume that the tree or trees in question were either oaks or terebinths. Whether it was a single tree or a grove is uncertain, but a large tree seems more likely since the author identifies it as a well known geographical marker.
It is a fact that trees were either gathering places for non-Israelite religious festivals or possibly objects thought to be sacred in themselves. Indeed, one form of the word in question (אלה - elah) can mean "god," "goddess" as well as oak or terebinth.  Israelites continued to meet at such trees to offer sacrifice and receive instruction (Judges 4:5, 1 Kings 14:22-24) even after such practices were banned after the establishment of the central temple in Jerusalem.
Since the word has many meanings, there is no consensus in regard to the OP's questions. Translators do sometimes allow their theological viewpoints to affect their interpretations, but one would need to ask them in order to be certain.

@ Dan Fefferman - The "banning" is mentioned in Deuteronomy 16:21: "Thou shalt not plant thee a grove of any trees near unto the altar of the LORD thy God..."  I wonder what the geography and landscape of Judea looked like in ancient times with much more trees or vegetation than today.
